# Pronoun ambiguity with titles

Tags: pronouns

I was wondering if the use of "it" is ambiguous in the following sentence:

"The XYZ is an excellent book, and it was later made into a movie."

The use of it refers to the book/XYZ vice versa. Is that allowed (pronoun referring to a noun that refers to another Noun) or which of the following would be the best option to use:

1. The XYZ is an excellent book, which was later made into a movie.
2. The XYZ is an excellent book that was later made into a movie.

And if "it" usage is correct grammatically, which one of the three (it, which, that) is the best option?

:)

Comment: I fail to see what could be confusing about the original sentence, since "is" implies an identity between the two options.

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com › blog › which-vs-that

Comment: IT itself is a pronoun, and of course, a pronoun can stand in place of a noun.  Re: WHICH and THAT, both are relative pronouns.

Answer (score -1):

[It depends on the clause](https://www.grammarly.com%20%E2%80%BA%20blog%20%E2%80%BA%20which-vs-that):

Use THAT for a defining clause: A defining clause (also called an essential clause or a restrictive clause) gives information essential to the meaning of the sentence.

Use WHICH to introduce a non-defining clause. Unlike defining clauses, non-defining clauses (also called nonessential or nonrestrictive clauses) don’t limit the meaning of the sentence and can be considered 'disposable'; you might lose some interesting details if you remove them, but the meaning of the sentence wouldn’t change.

Strictly speaking, your example is probably a WHICH, noting your correct use of the comma with "which" and its omission with "that".